# How to get next n[0:1] letter after each loop cycle in Python?

Tags: python

i got this python script:
The problem is i would like this loop to repeat but each time, it checks the next letter of the input, so loop1: n[0:1]   loop2: n[1:2] and so on...

```
import time

while True:
     
    n = input("Ltr:")
    h = n[0:1]

    if h==' ':
      print("        ")
      time.sleep(0.001)

    if h=='a':
      print("01100001")
      time.sleep(0.001)
      
    if h=='b':
      print("01100010")
      time.sleep(0.001)
      
    if h=='c':
      print("01100011")
      time.sleep(0.001)
      
    if h=='d':
      print("01100100")
      time.sleep(0.001)
```

So it basically goes on from a to z, also counts spaces and only supports lowercase letters.
If you already got it, it's an english-to-binary translator i'm trying to make, i dont want to import anything like plusgins and stuff, i want t make it by myself but i struggling with this... :(
Is there anyway to make it work ?

Comment: I think you just need `h = n[idx]`, and set `idx = 0` right before `while`, and then `idx = idx + 1` at the very end. That will cause a different problem when you run out of input, but it will iterate through the input. Also, your `n = input...` should be before `while`.

Comment: @NathanielFord Thanks, i'm going to try this out

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-binary/) you can simply do the following:

```
test = input("enter text")
res = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in test)
```

and `res` will contain your converted text.

If you are insisting on iterating through the string you can do the following:

```
string = input("enter string")
res = ''
for char in string:
   res += format(ord(char), '08b')
```